# Do pre-modern depictions of Varaha show him lifting a flat Earth?

Tags: earth, geography, varaha

[This site](http://www.iskcon-truth.com/bhu-mandala/varaha-earth-globe-lifting.html) claims that pre-modern paintings and sculptures of Varaha show him lifting a flat earth as opposed to a round earth.

My question is, are there any pre-modern depictions of Varaha that show him lifting a ROUND earth?

Comment: Your question in body is opposite to that in title.